# Could someone recommend a book for surveying species?

Tags: taxonomy, book-recommendation

I'm trying to get/renew basic knowledge of species. Could someone recommend a book for surveying "important"/"representational" species? I am looking for a book with good illustrations and that covers most "important"/"representational" species.

I am currently reading [The Tree of Life: A Phylogenetic Classification](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674021835), and it is thicker than I want to read as a first book in this kind.

Comment: The book you are using is the one I was going to recommend. With perhaps 8.7 million species (http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pbio.1001127), there is no short route.

Comment: If you are OK with a web solution, this answer (http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/395/107) might be useful.

Comment: Most general surveys of species I've seen (in school, for instance) tend to go through the [phyla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylum#Animal_phyla) (for animals) and the [divisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylum#Plant_divisions) (for plants) and looks at the general characteristics of each group. Would that be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Yes.  That will be sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your response to Gurav in the comments, it sounds like introductory zoology and plant biology texts would fit the bill.

For zoology, we teach from Hickman et al's [Integrated Principles of Zoology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073040509). It outlines the major phyla, their defining characteristics, with plenty of specific examples scattered throughout. There are nice little problem sets throughout, and it goes into a solid amount of detail for a first or second year zoology course.

For plants, I've used Graham et al's [Plant Biology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131469061), which takes a similar general approach. Though it's perhaps a bit broader, and less species-focused.

Both of these books outline the major relevant groups, and use 'representative' species to illustrate various biological points throughout. They might be a good place to start!